# Calculating current through a resistor

Tags: current

I have trouble calculating the current through R4, could somebody help me please.
I thought the current through the resistor R4 can be calculated like this:

Ir4 = I×(R4 ∥ (R3 + (R2 ∥ R1)) / R4), where I is the current from the source. I compared the result to a simulation and it is wrong, I don't know where my fault is. I would be glad about some help

[image]

EDIT: R2 and R3 are parallel, redrawn circuit:

[image]

Comment: You can use the built-in CircuitLab schematic tool to redraw your circuit into a more conventional layout. Why have you got R2 || R1 in your equation?

Comment: I am using Matlab

Comment: @Transistor i thought that r2 and r1 are parallel

Comment: Do you know how to do nodal analysis?

Comment: @MissMulan apparently not

Comment: For R1 and R2 to be in parallel they would have to share nodes. R1 and R2 connect at the "tee" in your circuit (one node) but their other ends are not connected so they are not in parallel. Two of the resistors are in parallel. Can you see which ones?

Comment: @MissMulan I also thought that Ir4 = I but the simulation says something else.

Comment: @MissMulan, that is not correct. Current will flow through every resistor. Do you know how to do nodal analysis? :^)

Comment: Yes I do but the fact there isnt a resistor(short circuit) confuses me.

Comment: @Transistor I don't know I would say that R4+R1 is parallel to R3

Comment: No. Read my definition again. Parallel resistors will share nodes. Don't confuse "node" with dots on your circuit schematic. R3 is in parallel with one other component. Can you see it yet?

Comment: @Transistor R2 and R3

Comment: Correct. Now redraw the circuit with R2 and R3 drawn in parallel - I suggest with vertical orientation. Add it into your question. Things should then become very clear.

Comment: Spoiler alert: R4 is connected directly across the supply, is it not?  So the other resistors are irrelevant.

Comment: @Frog, it's driven by a current source - not a voltage source. Maybe your comment is irrelevant? ;^)

Comment: @Transistor my bad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partial solution to lead OP's thinking.

[image]

*Figure 1. Original circuit layout.*

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvCHjK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 2. Exactly the same circuit but with more obvious parallel components R2 and R3.*

[image]

*Figure 3. Why is this not correct?*

Figure 3 can't be correct because it shows "R2 || R3" in series with R4. Figure 1 clearly shows that R4 is connected in parallel with the current source so Figure 3 is incorrect.

Comment: @MissMulan, see Figure 2. The "short-circuit" is still between R2 and R3's common node, but as you can see it doesn't eliminate them from the circuit. The R1-R2-R3 combination will steer some of the current away from R4.